# Processing weird Null Pointer Exception (something with PGraphics)

Tags: processing

For whatever reason when I run my program I get a NullPointerException. Here is the crash log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.awt.PGraphicsJava2D.getRaster(PGraphicsJava2D.java:2727)
    at processing.awt.PGraphicsJava2D.loadPixels(PGraphicsJava2D.java:2751)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.initCache(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:6471)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.getTexture(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:6424)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL$TexCache.getTexture(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:7464)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.flushPolys(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:2430)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.flush(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:2371)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.endDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1540)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2436)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$DrawListener.display(PSurfaceJOGL.java:884)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$MainTask.run(FPSAnimator.java:178)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
For more information, read revisions.txt and Help ? Troubleshooting.
```

This only happens when I use P2D/P3D. JAVA2D works just fine, but I want to use P2D because otherwise the program is laggy as heck.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Note that this should **note** be you entire sketch. Just enough code so we can copy and paste to see the error.

Comment: @IqPGM Any chance you can post the full code ? My hunch is you don't use the same renderer in the main sketch as you do in the PGraphics (e.g. use ```P2D``` in both ```size()``` and ```createGraphics()```.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks, this worked. I didn't know about this param in `createGraphics()`. Thanks again.

Comment: @lqPGM Awesome! I've added the above note as an answer for easy future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check you're using an explicit renderer for both your sketch and the PGraphics, especially for GL renderers (e.g. `P2D`/`P3D`).

For example:

```
PGraphics buffer;

void setup(){
  size(400,400,P3D);

  buffer = createGraphics(width,height,P3D);
  buffer.beginDraw();
  buffer.background(0);
  buffer.sphereDetail(4);
  buffer.noFill();
  buffer.endDraw();

}
void draw(){
  float size = map(sin(frameCount * .01),-1.0,1.0,0.0,100.0);  

  buffer.beginDraw();
  buffer.stroke(255,size * 0.5);
  buffer.translate(mouseX,mouseY,0);
  buffer.rotate(frameCount * 0.01,0.5,0.5,1.0);
  buffer.sphere(size);
  buffer.endDraw();

  image(buffer,0,0); 
}
```